# Is it correct and natural to say "book someone in with a dentist" meaning to make an appointment for someone with a dentist?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice

Is it correct and natural to say *book someone in with a dentist* meaning to make an appointment for someone with a dentist? For example:

> Remember that I **booked you in with** a dentist for tomorrow at 12 PM.

If it's not natural, what would you say to convey the message?

Comment: Yes, it's a very usual idiomatic and natural expression.

Comment: No, not book in. I made an appointment for you at the dentist. Book an appointment is more for business people and suchlike.

Comment: @Lambie.  I totally disagree.  This is perfectly acceptable informal conversational native English.  It's exactly what I would say.

Comment: Maybe it's regional. To me, in the US, "book someone in" would be done at their arrival somewhere, not when making an appointment. I agree, "book an appointment" is natural, without "in".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd understand that,  I don't find "I booked you in..." to be particularly strange.

I'd prefer saying "Remember you have a dentist appointment"   or similar. I think its better to use "You..." instead of "I..."  since it doesn't really matter who made the appointment.